# check the dns record for a hostname with nslookup

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a host list `hostfile` that i'm doing name lookup just to know if the host has records in DNS or not with the help of Linux native tool `nslookup`.

Below is what i'm doing and its working, however there is a situation when `nslookup` don't find anything thus the `result` is nothing in that case i want to fill "no dns record"

What i'm trying:

```
$ for i in `cat hostfile`;
> do
> echo $i $result
> result=$(nslookup $i | awk 'FNR==6{print $2}')
> done
```

OR

```
for i in `cat hostfile`; 
do 
printf "$i: %s\\n" $(nslookup $i | awk 'FNR==6{print $2}'); 
done
```

Its not giving correct output if there is no `nslookup` found.

**Desired:**

```
myhosts01       192.168.1.1
myhosts02       192.168.1.2
myhosts03       192.168.1.3
myhosts04       192.168.1.4
myhosts03       no dns record
myhosts04       no dns record
```

Comment: [Don' read lines with for](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) this ain't `python` and the likes. Also make sure there are no carriage returns on the files.

Comment: @Jetchisel, i'm agree then what you suggest to use for a very small set of data , however there is no carriage returns on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a full `if` statement to check whether the `result` is blank (`-z` for zero-length):

```
if [[ -z "$result" ]]; then
    result="no dns record"
fi
echo "$i $result"
```

Or use a [default value](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) when expanding the variable:

```
echo "$i ${result:-no dns record}"
```

In either case, I'd recommend using a `while read` loop to read the file instead of `for` (assuming there's one hostname per line), using `dig +short` instead trying to parse `nslookup`, doing the lookup *before* printing the result, and double-quoting all variable references (and probably using more descriptive variable names). Something like this:

```
while read -r hostname; do
    hostIP=$(dig +short "$hostname")
    echo "$hostname ${hostIP:-no dns record}"
done <hostfile
```